# amazon music lyrics display in python

Tags: python, user-interface

im triing to make a amazon music looking lyrics display. lyrics scolling up when the songs lyrics gets pass the the middle of the screen and the current words of the song is bolded. I am using python 3.10.

```
import datetime
import pygame
import time


line = ["Catch my eye, take my hand", "This bond is tighter than we ever planned", "Give me courage, so I can land", "We know that divided we'll fall", "So together we stand", "Climb with me, share my dreams", "Tomorrow's brighter than it's ever been", "Fear no danger, make big plans", "We know that divided we'll fall", "So together we stand", "Laugh and cry with me", "Fly that high with me", "See the sunset and the sunrise", "The world looks so good through our eyes", "Like the moon and stars at night", "Rest your head, tell me your thoughts", "Everything I have and called mine is all yours", "Sail that ocean, find that sand", "We know that divided we'll fall", "So together we stand", "♫", "Reach with me, see the sky", "I'll always be here for the rest of your life", "Side by side, hand in hand", "We speak a language no one else can understand", "Hear those cheers, strike up the band", "We know that divided we'll fall", "So together we stand", "We know that divided we'll fall", "So together we stand"]
space = "----->"
delay = [15.787806, 5.462624, 5.15232, 3.935717, 5.34453, 4.896048, 5.016052, 5.695679, 3.791529, 4.6244, 2.976378, 2.712208, 2.823541, 2.58344, 5.776433, 4.824529, 5.591887, 4.951168, 3.864145, 3.864145, 41.42448, 5.343489, 5.87241, 4.928067, 5.702866, 5.290941, 3.93323, 7.824845, 3.119874, 10.280221]
while True:
    while True:
        ask = input("do you wont to practice (a) with voice in song or (b) without voice in song\ntype a or b in the chat to chose\n>>>")
        if(ask.lower() == "a"):
            print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nTogether We Stand\nby Hans Zimmer & Steve Mazzaro\n")
            print(space + line[0])
            print(space + line[1])
            print(space + line[2])
            print(space + line[3])
            print(space + line[4])
            pygame.mixer.init()
            pygame.mixer.music.load("./The Boss Baby Family Business/voice/Together We Stand.mp3")
            pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)
            break
        elif(ask.lower() == "b"):
            print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nTogether We Stand\nby Hans Zimmer & Steve Mazzaro\n")
            print(space + line[0])
            print(space + line[1])
            print(space + line[2])
            print(space + line[3])
            print(space + line[4])
            pygame.mixer.init()
            pygame.mixer.music.load("./The Boss Baby Family Business/no voice/Together We Stand.mp3")
            pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)
            break
        else:
            print("not an option try again")

    for i in range(len(line)):
        if(i+5 < len(line)):
            print(space + line[i + 5])
            time.sleep(delay[i])
        else:
            print("")
            time.sleep(delay[i])
    print("Finished")
    ask = input("do you wont to play again?")
    if(ask.lower() == "yes" or ask.lower() == "y"):
        pass
    elif(ask.lower() == "no" or ask.lower() == "n"):
        quit()
    else:
        while(ask.lower() != "yes" or ask.lower() != "no" or ask.lower() != "y" or ask.lower() != "n"):
            if(ask.lower() == "yes" or ask.lower() == "y"):
                break
            elif(ask.lower() == "no" or ask.lower() == "n"):
                quit()
            else:
                ask = input("not a choice try again.\ndo you wont to play again?")
```

I want to make a GUI that highlights (aka: bolds) what part of the song its at, thats all.
if any one can help me make this look like what amazon music does with lyrics its you guys.

---

---

---